# Most efficient way to initialize a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

Whats the most efficient way to initialize a matrix in Python without using numpy.  For example I'd like to create:

```
matrix = [
           [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
           [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
           [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
         ]
```

I was creating one using:

```
dpcols = [[0,0]] * len(matrix[0])
matrix = [dpcols] * len(matrix)
```

But with this, if i change

```
matrix[1][1] = [1,1]
```

Then indexes [0][1], [1][1], and [2][1] all gets changed to [1,1], due to them all being linked together.

Comment: why the requirement of not using numpy?

Comment: Its just a restriction, cant use certain libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is as efficient as numpy since it's a double for loop, but it's easy to write:

```
>>> rows,cols = 2,3
>>> a = [[[0,0] for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]
>>> a
[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
>>> a[1][1] = [1,1]
>>> a
[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0]]]
```

Comment: `matrix = [[[0, 0] for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]` in his use-case

Comment: Was wondering if there are other ways without using 2 loops, but i guess this is the best i can do.  Thanks for the help